# Can you use the Facebook API to delete old posts?

Tags: facebook

I am new to using the Facebook API and just started playing around with it.
I was wondering if it is possible, for example an app, to delete past posts (that exists on the timeline, i.e, Can an app have the functionality to delete posts that exists before the app was started?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the [relevant documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post), **you are able to delete a post *only* if it was your application that created it.**

> An app can delete a post if it published it

You have not stated which language/SDK you are using, but the above link has examples for each supported SDK.

Here is an example using the PHP SDK:

```
$response = $facebook->api(
    "/{post-id}",
    "DELETE"
);
```

What you would need to do is make a `DELETE` request to `/post_id`.

Keep in mind that you will need the [`publish_actions` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) to perform this action.

Comment: Yes, I was actually using the PHP SDK. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Thank you @Lix for the answer but the documentation link seems broken. Maybe this one is the current one : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#deleting

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky - the answer is yes and no.

You can use the API to get a *list* of old posts, but then you need to delete them via the browser.  This tool does just that:

https://github.com/chander/social-network-cleaner

However, it's written in Python and requires a bit of tech know-how.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now

Delete a Post
To delete a Page post, send a DELETE request to the /{page-post-id} endpoint.

Before You Start
You will need the following:

The pages_manage_posts permission

The pages_read_engagement permission

A Page access token requested by a person who is able to perform the CREATE_CONTENT task on the Page that is being queried
Sample Request

```
curl -i -X DELETE "https://graph.facebook.com/{page-post-id}
  ?access_token={page-access-token}"
```

On success, your app receives the following response:

```
{
  "success": true
}
```